# BigCommerce Lifestyle theme - add to cart show quickview instead of redirect to cart

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

i'm using the LifeStyle default theme for our bigcommerce based website, and i'm having difficulties figuring out how to use the quickview dialog instead of redirecting to the cart when I click dd to cart from the homepage (it works as I want it to from product section)

https://themes.psdcenter.com/theme-documentation/lifestyle-bigcommerce-theme-manual/

any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is being set by a dynamic {{add_to_cart_url}} in the card.html file, found through templates > components > products. I agree that this information is not located in the docs by lifestyle developers.

You always have the option to reach out to the theme developers for some guidance/best practice advice from them directly when making this customization.

Some options to consider: You could write a script that overrides this default behavior, but that may not be the best route. You could also look at writing custom login in card.html specifically for the homepage. And based on card.html, it looks like to open quick view, the button has a class  of 'quickview' which could be what's targeting the modal action. You could test with adding this class and making other modifications to the card.html. Search the card.html file for 'theme_settings.show_product_quick_view' to see how this works to help you achieve this on the homepage.